# phpmyadmin working when i turn off certain vhosts

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

Pretty confused right now, while i feel i know a bit about vhosts this has confused me for no end of time and i thought i'll seek help after so long :p

I turn off 1 vhost and phpmyadmin will work locally, turn this vhost back on, phpmyadmin ends up at this webpage with my 404 for the site. the vhost in question:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
DocumentRoot /var/www/mayfieldafc/docroot
ServerName mayfieldafc.com
ServerAlias mayfieldafc.local
#CustomLog logs/mayfieldafc-transfer.log combined
#ErrorLog logs/mayfieldafc-error.log

php_value include_path "/usr/share/php:/var/www/mayfieldafc"
php_value error_reporting 2047
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
php_flag short_open_tag off

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

<Directory /var/www/mayfieldafc/docroot>
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

RewriteEngine on
#RewriteLogLevel 9
#RewriteLog /var/log/mod_rewrite.log

# Dispatcher wiring
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !dispatch\.php$
RewriteCond /var/www/mayfieldafc/docroot%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(/.*)$ /dispatch.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
DocumentRoot /var/www/mayfieldafc/docroot
ServerName assets.mayfieldafc.com
ServerAlias assets-mayfieldafc.local
#CustomLog logs/mayfieldafc-transfer.log combined
#ErrorLog logs/mayfieldafc-error.log

DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

<Directory /var/www/mayfieldafc/docroot>
    Options None
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

If anybody knows anything about vhosts and phpmyadmin i'd love you forever :D

Comment: sorry for this stupid question. what url do you use to connect to your webpage? are you using http: //127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: Do you have NameVirtualHost set in your config?

Comment: As for url's: http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ where phpmyadmin is in my root folder and http://mayfieldafc.local/ for the vhost above. I have no turned all other vhosts off and am only currently running the mayfield vhost. Also thanks for the promot replies guys :)

Comment: So in the httpd.conf i've got NameVirtualHost *:80

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end nothing i could change in my vhost settings was working so i went with the obvious answer.

I just created a separate vhost with a

```
servername phpmyadmin.local
```

and just pointing the document to myphpadmin on my hard drive and all was good.

Answer (score 1):

Using NameVirtualHost to host multiple sites on one IP address requires that you access the VirtualHost at its name and not its IP address.  Hence, if phpmyadmin is hosted on assets-mayfieldafc.local, you *must* access it at assets-mayfieldafc.local/phpmyadmin.  It works at localhost when only one virtualhost is configured as it only has one place to go for the localhost IP.  Configure more virtualhosts on the same IP, and you will need to access them by ServerName/ServerAlias.